# mysql mapping a value to a default value when not found in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, mapping, default-value

I have this table in mySQL intended to map some values to other values, for example countries to capitals.

I want to use it this way:

```
SELECT capital
FROM CountryData
WHERE country = 'France';
```

or rather, to update some other table:

```
UPDATE CustomerData
SET customerCapital =
   SELECT capital
   FROM CountryData
   WHERE CountryData.country = CustomerData.customerCountry
```

The problem arises when the country is not found in the `Country` table. How can I have `customerCapital` set to some default value `'UNKNOWN'` instead of `NULL` when `customerCountry` is not present in the `CountryData` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `COALESCE` function.

However, I do not advise you to store an arbitrary value instead of NULL. Any other value than NULL **is an information in itself**. You want to show the lack of value, therefore you should use NULL.
It sounds like a cosmetic problem. If you want to show a value when you print the customerCapital to the screen, then you should, in the application code, transform the NULL into `UNKNOWN`.